# How do I call data from a table in a database into a java class in netbeans?

Tags: java, sql, database, netbeans, derby

first time posting so sorry if my question is slightly strange.

So I have a project in school that requires us to create java classes using netbeans that open up a window with three options, check stock, purchase item and update stock.

We had a class called stockdata that held the details of 5 different items for us to use in our three classes to check, purchase and update items. The latest stage of our coursework requires us to create a derby database and enter the items into a table.

I have done this with no issues but I am having a problem getting the items from the table back into my classes to use. We were given the following code but I can't get it to work, even using the commented hints.

```
package stock;

// Skeleton version of StockData.java that links to a database.
// NOTE: You should not have to make any changes to the other
// Java GUI classes for this to work, if you complete it correctly.
// Indeed these classes shouldn't even need to be recompiled
import java.sql.*; // DB handling package
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.derby.drda.NetworkServerControl;

public class StockData {

    private static Connection connection;
    private static Statement stmt;

    static {
    // standard code to open a connection and statement to an Access         database
        try {
            NetworkServerControl server = new NetworkServerControl();
            server.start(null);
            // Load JDBC driver
            Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver");
            //Establish a connection
            String sourceURL = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/"
                    + new File("UserDB").getAbsolutePath() + ";";
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(sourceURL, "use",   "use");
            stmt = connection.createStatement();
    } // The following exceptions must be caught
    catch (ClassNotFoundException cnfe) {
        System.out.println(cnfe);
    } catch (SQLException sqle) {
        System.out.println(sqle);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }

}

// You could make methods getName, getPrice and getQuantity simpler by using an auxiliary
// private String method getField(String key, int fieldNo) to return the appropriate field as a String
public static String getName(String key) {
    try {
        // Need single quote marks ' around the key field in SQL. This is easy to get wrong!
        // For instance if key was "11" the SELECT statement would be:
        // SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE stockKey = '11'
        ResultSet res = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM Stock WHERE stockKey = '" + key + "'");
        if (res.next()) { // there is a result
            // the name field is the second one in the ResultSet
            // Note that with  ResultSet we count the fields starting from 1
            return res.getString(2);
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}

public static double getPrice(String key) {
    // Similar to getName. If no result, return -1.0
    return 0;
}

public static int getQuantity(String key) {
    // Similar to getName. If no result, return -1

    return 0;
}

// update stock levels
// extra is +ve if adding stock
// extra is -ve if selling stock
public static void update(String key, int extra) {
    // SQL UPDATE statement required. For instance if extra is 5 and stockKey is "11" then updateStr is
    // UPDATE Stock SET stockQuantity = stockQuantity + 5 WHERE stockKey = '11'
    String updateStr = "UPDATE Stock SET stockQuantity = stockQuantity + " + extra + " WHERE stockKey = '" + key + "'";
    System.out.println(updateStr);
    try {
        stmt.executeUpdate(updateStr);
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}

// close the database
public static void close() {
    try {
        connection.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        // this shouldn't happen
        System.out.println(e);
    }
}
```

}

Sorry if this seems a stupid question but I am fairly new to Java and was making good progress until this roadblock.

Thanks in advance!

Alex

Comment: I'm sorry for still sounding dumb guys, the thing that is getting to me is that in the comments my professor has provided in the Stock Data class, it says that if I code that class correctly I won't even need to change anything in my other classes. 

I know it is just a simple piece of code that needs to go under the getName, getPrice, getQuantity method headers but I can't figure it out, can you guys elaborate any further on exactly what code will need to go in these methods? Also, do I need to do anything further in SQL in the table? I've populated it with PRODUCT_ID (primary key).

Comment: PRODUCT_NAME, PRICE, STOCK_LEVEL as my columns and i've even added 9 items into the table. Is that all I need to do on that side of it? Is it just in the Stock Data class that I pasted in my original post where I need to write some code to be able to use the data in my table for my classes?

If there is any additional information you need to help me further, just ask. 

Again, i'm sorry if I am not making much sense, i'm still very new to Java!

Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Searching for "java sql" on Google delivers this link: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html

From a connection you can create a statement (you can find this in the link and in your code) , then fetch a result set and loop over that with rs.next(). That should get your started.

Of course you have to make sure that the driver and database are there/running, just saying...

Answer (score 0):

Here netbeans has nothing to do with database. This is a Java-based integrated development environment(IDE) that will help you to reduce syntactic error.

```
public void dataAccess(){
```

`try {
        String connectionUrl = "suitable connection url as per your database";
        Connection con = null;
        Statement stmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
            Class.forName("JDBC driver name as per your database");
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);
            String SQL = "SQL query as per your criteria";
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
            while (rs.next()) {
                // look into ResultSet api and use method as per your requirement
            }
            rs.close();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {

        //log error message ;
    }

}`